# How to authorize in ASP.NET Core 2 using jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using the `[Authorize]` attribute for authentification in my controller, but when I get a request to `TestMethod` I  get an error: "500 Internal..".

What am I doing wrong??

That my code from `StartUp.cs`

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy =
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Identity.Application")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

services
    .AddAuthentication(option =>
    {
        option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters =
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                SaveSigninToken = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://blabla/",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "http://blabla/",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = blabla.bla(),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            };
    });

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddMvc();
```

And also code from Controller

```
[Route("test"), HttpPost]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public void Test() { }
```

Do you have ideas?

I'm using these libraries to generate the token:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

Comment: Have you add `app.UseAuthentication()` in your middleware pipeline? and also why do you write `AddAuthentication` twice?

Comment: @Kahbazi yeah, "app.UseAuthentication()" is added. Next.. so, it's "trash" after tests, sorry, for bad code, i will delete this.

Comment: how are you trying to login?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane login is successful, after i'm generating Token.
My problem: i can't get access to method with [Authorize] prefix, i'm getting 500 error.

Comment: your actual 500 error should be shown somewhere in the console

Comment: @Neville Nazerane No way, i'm use API for my WebSite, and my WebSite get 500 error, at the moment after request.

Comment: do you have logging for your api that has the scheme? also i hope the controller and scheme are in the same project

Comment: @Neville Nazerane No, it's in the same solution, but other projects..

Comment: You need to run within the debugger attached to your API project. An `HTTP 500` response is just a generic "something went wrong" error. You need to see what the actual exception at the API level is.

Comment: ok, that is exactly what I asked. If you have two projects you need to debug both so you can actually see your error.

Comment: so let me get this right. You have **project A** running your API, where you set up the authentication scheme and you have **project B** where you have your `Test` function?

Comment: Neville Nazerane Oh, i did this, i have debug in 3 projects, else i can't test "function". So, i have 3 projects, 1 - WebSite where is data post to next project - 2 - Api where is data post to next project - 3 Authorize - here data is checking, if user was detected and allright -> create token and return this. And 3 -> 2 -> 1 return. So, when i'm trying call my fuction in API, from WebSite, i'm post my data with token in the header. But i can't debbug this due-to [Authorize]. I really haven't ideas.

Comment: You should use a software like Postman to test requests to your API, and your api should be able to operate independent to any other projects that might consume it. also Does the request work when you remove the authorize tag?

Comment: @Kevin I'm use Fiddler, yes, request is work, if i will delete tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the  [Authorize] attribute you need to make a policy:

```
     //new policy makes [Authorize] availible by claims

  services.AddAuthorization((options) => {
                options.AddPolicy("MyNewPolicy", policybuilder =>
                {               
                    policybuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policybuilder.RequireClaim("role", "someClaim");

                });
            });

//usage

        [Authorize(Roles = "someClaim")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> About(){


}

//to awnsr your comment add a list of claims to your user class ex:

   new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId="1001",
                    Username="Frank",
                    Password="password",

                    Claims= new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("given_name","Frank"),
                        new Claim("family_name","Underwood"),
                        new Claim("address","1 addy rd unit 233"),                
                        new Claim("role", "someClaim")


                    }

                }
```

Comment: No way, i have differently claims for all authorized users

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a lot of issues when tryout out `AddJwtBearer`. Finally I found out that making a manual login wasn't that much harder, worked easily and is also easier to debug.

Basically, first I created a helper class for creating and validating tokens. Here is the source code for the class: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore-jwt-sample/blob/master/website/TokenGenerator.cs. Everything you had added in your `TokenValidationParameters` can go inside this class.

Once you have that, here is a Boiler plate authentication scheme:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
}

public class TokenAuthentication : AuthenticationHandler<TokenAuthenticationOptions>
{

    public const string SchemeName = "TokenAuth";

    public TokenAuthentication(IOptionsMonitor<TokenAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, 
                                UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) 
                                    : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Authenticate());
    }

    private AuthenticateResult Authenticate()
    {
        string auth, token;
        auth = Context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (auth == null) return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No JWT token provided");
        var auths = auth.Split(" ");
        if (auths[0].ToLower() != "bearer") return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid authentication");
        token = auths[1];

        try
        {
            var generator = new TokenGenerator();
            var principal = generator.Validate(token);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, SchemeName));
        }
        catch
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Failed to validate token");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in your start up you can use this scheme this way:

```
services.AddAuthentication(TokenAuthentication.SchemeName)
    .AddScheme<TokenAuthenticationOptions, TokenAuthentication>
            (TokenAuthentication.SchemeName, o => { });
```

Comment: it's doesn't work :(
I'm getting "error 500" still, when i'm trying get access to function with [Authorize] prefix

Comment: ok, put a breakpoint on `var auths = auth.Split(" ")` and run it. don't you see the error message on the console?

Comment: @Marc LaFleur - MSFT No way, i have this error from [authorize] i can't check and from this.